# How to get timezone in GMT Form in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

In my iPhone app I want to get system timezone in GMT. Am Using the following code.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"zzz";
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *timeZoneString=[timeStamp substringFromIndex:3];
    [dateFormatter release];
```

Am getting timezone in GMT form in iOS5 but not in iOS6. How to get timezone in GMT form in iOS6? Please Help!!!

Comment: How about this, `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];` in place of `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];`? Does that work?

Comment: What do you get in iOS6?

Comment: Probably abbreviationDictionary(class method of NSTimeZone) is causing you problem. Check logging abbreviationDictionary in both ios5 & ios6, you will see the difference. However you can change it.

Comment: So did it work? Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can check with,

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

in place of,

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have revised @ACB's code as there were a few typos , try `[dateFormatter setTimezone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];` instead of `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];`.  This seems to work for me.

I would like to give credit for this answer to @ACB.  He/she came up with this technique and I only confirmed it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I have added as answer. That was a guess which I couldn't verify before posting and hence added as comment.

Comment: would you like me to erase this answer?